# How to control template in gridview yii2 advanced template?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to give if condition to control the action buttons(view, edit and delete) in the `template attribute` and also add new buttons.
I have this code, but something is wrong:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template'=>function ($session){
        if($session->get('userType') != 'admin'){
            '{view}{update}{delete}';
        }else{

            'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}{activate}{deactivate}',
            'buttons' => [
                'deactivate' => function ($url,\backend\models\Document $model) {
                    if($model->Status==1)
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon  glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'deactivate'),
                        ]);
                    },
                'activate' => function ($url, $model) {
                    if($model->Status==0)
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'activate'),
                        ]);
                    },
                ],
            }
        },
    ],
```

But I got this error :

```
Object of class Closure could not be converted to string
```

I am using session object as a parameter in the function.
how to fix that, or what is the perfect way to check with if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an anonymous function

```
 'template'=>function ( ... ) {}
```

but call an external function or directly use a proper assigment by  code eg:

```
'template'=> (if($session->get('userType') != 'admin')) ? '{view}{update}{delete}' : '{view}{update}{delete}{activate}{deactivate}',


public function myTemplate($session){
   ....
   return yourResult;

}
```

then

```
'template'=> myTemplate($session),
```